# Finding minimum elevation along the edges of polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, elevation, 3d-analyst

I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have a polygon and a raster, and I would like to know what the lowest elevation is along the edges of the polygon.

I would want each polygon to have a field that has the lowest elevation/raster value along the edges of each polygon

I have 3D Analyst extension.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your polygons to line features then use the [Add Surface Information](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/add-surface-information.htm) tool in the 3D Analyst tools to populate those lines with the z_min value.  Failing to do so will populate the polygon with the lowest elevation value in the polygon and not on the line that defines the polygon.  Convert your processed lines back to a polygon if necessary.

These ESRI tools that use both raster and vector data are sensitive to coordinate reference systems(CRS).  Ensure that your raster surface and vector data share a CRS or you will likely get a 999999 error when running this tool.

Comment: when I convert the lines back to polygons I lose the min value attribute. How do I keep this when I convert the lines back to polygons?

Comment: This is one to many situation. You could create a table with each line's lowest value, then join to this using the polygon identifier. Or, just keep the lines and relate them spatially to their polygon, if needed, or use them for labeling/mapping.